# Seeking DynamoDb2 Connection Tutorial - getting error

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I've starting working with dynamodb2.

I need to do the following:
1. Connect to dynamo
2. Access tables by name
3. Scan them for specific values

My question is primarily looking for a good example. I haven't found any that worked yet.

I am using the following example (see: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamodb2_tut.html):

```
def process_segment(segment=0, total_segments=10):
    # This method/function is executed in each thread, each getting its
    # own segment to process through.
    conn = boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region(
        'us-east-1',
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    )
    table = Table('users', connection=conn)
```

I have:

```
_aws_access_key_id=awsAccess.aws_access_key_id
_aws_secret_access_key=awsAccess.aws_secret_access_key
_aws_dynamo_region=awsAccess.aws_dynamo_region
credentials ={_aws_access_key_id,_aws_secret_access_key}

decompiled_dynamo_table="decompiled_swfs"
text_dynamo_table="decompiled_swf_text"
image_dynamo_table="images_decompiled"
_dynamo_table="decompiled_swf_text"

dynamoConn= dynamodb2.connect_to_region(region_name=_aws_dynamo_region,aws_access_key_id=_aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=_aws_secret_access_key)
```

I'm getting the this error:

> pydev debugger: starting (pid: 95304) Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.4.1.201403181715/pysrc/pydevd.py",
>   line 1844, in 
>       debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)   File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.4.1.201403181715/pysrc/pydevd.py",
>   line 1372, in run
>       pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script   File
>   "/Users/tai/Documents/workspace/testSelenium/testS/**init**.py", line
>   23, in 
>       import dynamoAccess   File "/Users/tai/Documents/workspace/testSelenium/testS/dynamoAccess.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       swfTable = Table(decompiled_dynamo_table, connection=dynamoConn)   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/dynamodb2/table.py",
>   line 107, in **init**
>       self.connection = DynamoDBConnection()   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py",
>   line 183, in **init**
>       super(DynamoDBConnection, self).**init**(**kwargs)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/connection.py",
>   line 1073, in **init**
>       profile_name=profile_name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/connection.py",
>   line 572, in **init**
>       host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/boto/auth.py",
>   line 883, in get_auth_handler
>       'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names))) boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to
>   authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check
>   your credentials

I checked the value of _aws_secret_access_key, _aws_access_key_id, etc is correct. They are strings. What's different? Does someone know of a better example or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error.

I was passing in us-east for region however the dynamodb2 lib is looking for us-east-1.

If you come across a similar error like this it is likely that the issue is not your id / key as those are already tested rather then location itself is not checked for.